# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook force re-login

Tags: .net, facebook, asp.net-core, authentication

I have implemented login through Facebook social using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook nuget. And I have requirement that each time user clicks login button the system should start login process with all permission asks again, like if it was first-time login through facebook. Also user should be able to choose another account. But when user click login button in second and further times - no login screen appeared and I just get access token of FB.
How can I force this login step again or there is no such possibility? Maybe I should clear cookies in user's browser.
I'm not very familiar with aspnetcore authentication and with browser things, because I'm Xamarin developer

What I have:

Initialization:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddFacebook(fb =>
        {
            fb.AppId = "784137845529334";
            fb.AppSecret = "7970214b88892ae601923f852ae79fcd";
            fb.SaveTokens = true;
        });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("LoginOrCreateAccount/{scheme}")]
    public async Task LoginOrCreateAccount([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
        var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

        if (!auth.Succeeded
            || auth?.Principal == null
            || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
        {
            // Not authenticated, challenge
            await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
        }
        else
        {
            var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
            var email = string.Empty;
            email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            // Get parameters to send back to the callback
            var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "access_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token") },
                { "refresh_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
                { "expires", (auth.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
                { "email", email }
            };

            // Build the result url
            var url = callbackScheme + "://#" + string.Join("&",
                qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
                .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

            // Redirect to final url
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to achieve your needs through `services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook()`, something like `ptompt=login`.

By looking for a lot of information, combined with your `LoginOrCreateAccount` method, I recommend that when you click the button, that is, in the front end `Enabling Re-Authentication`.

**Facebook offical doc :** [Re-Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/#----)